# How to prevent upload kitchensink workflow in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netflix, conductor, netflix-conductor

I run Netflix conductor docker (conductor/docker docker-compose.yaml).
Docker starts and uploads workflows:

- ephemeralKitchenSinkEphemeralTasks
- ephemeralKitchenSinkStoredTasks
- kitchensink

How I can prevent running these workflows?

Comment: Solved!
Solution: set loadSample to false in docker/server/config/config-local.properties and in  docker/server/config/config.properties

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Solution: set loadSample to false in docker/server/config/config-local.properties and in docker/server/config/config.properties